# Undo field calculation in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, undo-redo

I am using ArcGIS Pro and cannot find a way to undo field calculations.

With ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop, field calculations could be undone when an edit session was active, but Pro seems to be in a perpetual edit session that does not include the ability to undo field calculations.

Is it possible to undo a field calculation in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this at ArcGIS Pro 1.3 and can confirm what you are saying.

I think the reason that field calculations cannot be undone is that they are not being done within an edit session, but rather by the Calculate Field tool of the Geoprocessing pane.

I think the only way to try and obtain the software behaviour that you seek is to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).  I could not see an existing one there.